Перенос слова, если в слоге одна гласная и далее слово продолжается
В частности, возможен ли такой перенос слова:
сво-ими
То есть "и" перенесена на новую строку.
Или допустимо только "свои-ми"?

Сво-ими, осозна-ете, вли-яли.

во-одушевление, при-оритет, и т. д.
